# Render person with presence

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, rest

How could I render a person with presence using JavaScript? Not in SharePoint result templates... I'm using REST and I'm getting the person from the web service

Comment: What type of presense do you want, the one that is to the left of an image or just the little square next to a persons name?

Comment: Just the little square

Answer (score 3):

For the "little square" use the following snippet:

```
<span>
 <span class="ms-imnSpan">
  <a href="#" onclick="IMNImageOnClick(event);return false;" class="ms-imnlink ms-spimn-presenceLink">
   <span class="ms-spimn-presenceWrapper ms-imnImg ms-spimn-imgSize-10x10">
    <img name="imnmark" title="" ShowOfflinePawn="1" class="ms-spimn-img ms-spimn-presence-disconnected-10x10x32" src="/_layouts/15/images/spimn.png?rev=23" alt="Presence" sip="@Model.ContactItem.Email" id="imn_1@Model.ContactItem.ID,type=smtp" />
   </span>
  </a>
 </span>
<span>
 <a href="#" onclick="IMNImageOnClick(event);return false;" class="ms-imnlink" tabIndex="-1">
<img name="imnmark" title="" ShowOfflinePawn="1" class="ms-hide" src="/_layouts/15/images/spimn.png?rev=23" alt="Presence" sip="@Model.ContactItem.Email" id="imn_2@Model.ContactItem.ID,type=smtp" />@Model.ContactItem.FirstName @Model.ContactItem.LastName</a>
</span>
</span>
```

Here is the markup to use for "user image with presence"

```
<div class="ms-tableCell">
    <span class="ms-imnSpan">
         <a class="ms-imnlink ms-spimn-presenceLink" onclick="IMNImageOnClick(event);return false;" href="#">
               <span class="ms-spimn-presenceWrapper ms-spimn-imgSize-5x48">
                        <img name="imnmark" title="" class="ms-spimn-img ms-spimn-presence-disconnected-5x48x32" id="imn_1@Model.ContactItem.ID,type=smtp" alt="" src="/_layouts/15/images/spimn.png?rev=23" sip="@Model.ContactItem.Email" showofflinepawn="1">
               </span>
         </a>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="ms-tableCell ms-verticalAlignTop">
     <div class="ms-peopleux-userImgDiv">
         <span class="ms-imnSpan">
              <a tabindex="-1" class="ms-imnlink" onclick="IMNImageOnClick(event);return false;" href="#">
                  <img name="imnmark" title="" class="ms-hide" id="imn_2@Model.ContactItem.ID,type=smtp" alt="" src="/_layouts/15/images/spimn.png?rev=23" sip="@Model.ContactItem.Email" showofflinepawn="1">
               </a>
               <a class="ms-subtleLink ms-peopleux-imgUserLink">
                     <span class="ms-peopleux-userImgWrapper" style="width: 48px; height: 48px;">
                          <img class="ms-peopleux-userImg" style="clip: rect(0px, 48px, 48px, 0px); min-height: 48px; min-width: 48px; max-width: 48px;" alt="@Model.ContactItem.FirstName @Model.ContactItem.LastName" src="@profileImage" />
                     </span>
                </a>
            </span>
        </div>
   </div>
```

It is extracted from a Razor view above so there are some parameters you need to replace:

- `@Model.ContactItem.ID` - any unique integer, we use the users ID
- `@Model.ContactItem.Email` - the users email-address
- `@Model.ContactItem.FirstName` - the users first name
- `@Model.ContactItem.LastName` - the users last name
- `@profileImage` - path to the users profile image

Also, you can find more snippets here: http://www.sharepointcolumn.com/lync-presence-indicators-code-snippets-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: This should be marked as answer! Although the link isn't accessible anymore though.

Comment: Almost, but the id properties must not contain space, so instead of id="imn_1 @Model.ContactItem.ID,type=smtp", it should be id="imn_1@Model.ContactItem.ID,type=smtp".

Comment: @JussiPalo feel free to add an edit suggestion to the post!